# ASP.NET Arabic text - Period incorrectly appearing at beginning of sentence

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, localization

I have an ASP.NET v4 form containing a `textarea` element with `dir` field set to `auto`:

```
<form runat="server">
    <textarea id="mytext" name="mytext" dir="auto" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 10px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Having set the language of my Windows OS to Arabic, when entering Arabic text into the text box, the direction of the text is right-to-left as expected. Also when submitting the form and inspecting the `Request.Form["mytext"]` in the code-behind, the text appears correct apart from the fact that the period character at the end of the final sentence (i.e. on the far left) has moved to the beginning of the first sentence (i.e. on the far right).

E.g (not using real Arabic words as I don't know the language):
before .بثبصبصببص.بثبثبثبصيص.ثاثقاثلثبص
after  بثبصبصببص.بثبثبثبصيص.ثاثقاثلثبص.

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: The text is in correct order ad you only see `.` at first because in the debugger, text boxes are left to right. It's enough to display the text in a text box having right to left style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you worry about having text with incorrect order, you should know when you entered text in an rtl text box and see it correctly, the text is in correct order

In debugger, you only see `.` at first because in the debugger, text boxes are left to right. It's enough to save received text and then when displaying, display the text in a text box having right to left style.

To enter `سلام علیکم.` correctly, enter in order, first `س` then `ل` then `ا`, ... and at last `.` :

<kbd>س</kbd>
<kbd>ل</kbd>
<kbd>ا</kbd>
<kbd>م</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd>
<kbd>ع</kbd>
<kbd>ل</kbd>
<kbd>ی</kbd>
<kbd>ک</kbd>
<kbd>م</kbd>
<kbd>.</kbd>

And it would display correctly in a textbox with `dir="rtl"` or `dir="auto"` as you see in the below sample:

```html
<html>
<head><title>auto-rtl-ltr</title></head>
<body>
  <input type="text" dir="auto" value="سلام علیکم."/>
  <input type="text" dir="rtl" value="سلام علیکم."/>
  <input type="text" dir="ltr" value="سلام علیکم."/>
</body>
</html>
```

Also as a test you can paste `سلام علیکم.` in notepad or a textbox and using left (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) and right(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) switch between ltr and rtl and see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.