# TextBox RTL with letters and numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

I set the `TextBox.RightToLeft` property to `Yes`.
When I'm entering this text: "a 32" the string that is stored
is "32 a".
the order of entering the text is: first <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd> and then<kbd>a</kbd>.

How can I have the value stored as entered?

Comment: With Visual Studio 2013 framework 4.5 i can't replicate your error...

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I get `"a 32"` as `textBox.Text` if i enter `"a 32"` with `textBox.RightToLeft` set to `true`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter enter `32 a` and it will appear as `a 32` because of `RightToLeft`.

Comment: @Shaharyar: as i've already told in my last comment, that is what i did and i couldn't reproduce it. Neither with `textBox.RightToLeft` set to `true` at design- nor at run-time. Or do you mean that it's diplayed in the `TextBox` in this way? Of course, that's what this property does. But OP is speaking about that the `Text`-property returns it in the wrong direction afterwards.

Comment: That is strange, I have re-produced it and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OP: How can I have the value stored as entered?

The string will be stored exactly in the same order you entered characters regardless of display settings of `TextBox`.

If you enter <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then your values will be stored in the same order and the value of `Text` property of `TextBox` will be `32 a` while it will be displayed different based on `RightToLeft` and `TextAlign` property.

Here is the result of entering the text in the order: <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.
Choose your desired setting, store the string and then show it again in a `TextBox` with the same settings.

[image]

Comment: but if RTL is yes and the align is left when i write: s= textBox1.Text; the value of s is "32 a". i want it to be "a 32"

Comment: I think the answer completely describes the situation. The storage and order of characters is the same as you enter. Choose the display settings based on what you see in the above image. And let me know if you have any question after reading the answer carefully :-)

Comment: its ok. my problem is with PDF textbox in hebrew the text is "א 32"
but if i click in the textbox it displaying corectly. probably font issue

Comment: Hebrew is a right to left language like Persian and Arabic. You should use correct right to left and text align property for text boxes and enter the text in the correct order in your language and it will save in the same order and it will show correctly in a text box with correct settings. You may also find this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/34619908/3110834

Comment: In my google search i found that the problem in PDF is due to missing embedded fonts

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Set your **TextBox** Property **RightToLeft** = NO and use **TextAlign** = Right.

Comment: The order of entering the text is: first "32" space and than "a".

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.90).aspx)

> If the value of the RightToLeft property is changed at run time, only
>   raw text without formatting is preserved.

You will have to reverse its order yourself:

```
string[] text = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //get string while preserving the words
Array.Reverse(text); //reverse the order of words (not their chars)
string finalValue = string.Join(" ", text); //make the string out of array
```

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it, even if i change that property at runtime.

Comment: Well I didn't check it, but MSDN says it. Let me try.

Comment: the order of entering the text is: first "32"  space and than "a"