# How can I fix the direction of a TextBox to be always left in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, textbox, text-alignment

I have a `textBox` and I want when I write into that `textBox` (*mix language [Persian, English]*) the words to be typed into that textbox in the same way as I typed.
This is the example:

This is the text I typed

> We/میلاد@12

but the  order was like that:

- 1. we
- 2. @
- 3. میلاد
- 4. /
- 5. 123

how can I fix this problem

Comment: If that is in a browser then css seems to do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770541/578411

Comment: @rene no I'm in winform

Comment: @rene how can i convert that into winform?

Comment: Did you set the [RightToLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?view=netcore-3.1)  property?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739602/textbox-rtl-with-letters-and-numbers/34747782#34747782

Comment: @rene yes i set that but because of the Persian language char, it's not working, but in html and css the link you send to me it's working, i need that into winform

Answer (score 0):

If you check

- the `RightToLeft` and
- the `TextAlign` Properties

your issue will be solved.

These are the Microsoft Documentations:

- [RightToLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?view=netcore-3.1)
- [TextAlign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign?view=netcore-3.1)

And below you can see these Properties how they appeared in the Properties Section in Visual Studio:
[image]
[image]

The values of the Properties in the pictures are indicative , change them accordingly as you want and your problem will be solved.